# What is rule in JavaFX Binding?

Tags: javafx, binding

I'm learning javafx Binding and read about it from [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#sthref8).
Then I tried to explore it more and found [javafx.beans.binding.Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html). As I saw all methods of this class required minimum One `ObservableValue`'s paramenter Why?

I mean why I can't make a binding like this.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 3;
Bindings.add(a,b);
```

Extra information will be appreciated, because I want to learn in depth.

Comment: Because that "binding" could be created like this `int c = a + b;` or `int c = Integer.sum(a, b);` if you prefer that.

Comment: What would you expect that binding to do? There is nothing for it to observe.

Comment: @James_D I'm learning that's why I'm confused why it not allowed? what is the reason? why minimum one ObservableValue's parameter required?

Comment: @fabian Really? But it is not working. `int a = 5;
  int b = 3;
  int c = a + b;
  
  System.out.println(c);
  
  b = 2;
  
  System.out.println(c);`

Comment: @Nothing You can only *observe* something that changes its value (or it only makes sense to do so), and has a mechanism for observing it. And `int` isn't mutable in the sense that you can't do `b=3;` and then `b.set(2);`, you can only *replace* its current value with a new value: `b=2;`. If the binding were observing *anything* (in any meaningful sense), it would still be observing the value `3` (which never changes).

Comment: Now making sense. Sorry for the stupid question. Just one thing more can you help me to understand the difference between. `Fluent API` and `factory methods` in binding?

Comment: That's just a matter of which you prefer. Consumer choice, if you will. They basically do the same thing.